# steam condenser java errors

Tags: java, eclipse, api, constructor, steam-condenser

I've been working on a little project involving Steam Condenser, a Steam API written in Java, but I haven't been able to actually do anything with it.

I'll explain. This is what the [wiki](https://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser/wiki/Usage-Examples-Java) tells me:

> SteamId id = new SteamId("demomenz");
>
> GameStats stats = id.getGameStats("tf2");
>
> List achievements = stats.getAchievements();

The problem is, eclipse doesn't like it apparently, as it spits out this error:

> The constructor SteamId(String) is undefined

and it gives me the option to change it to:

> SteamId id = new SteamId("demomenz", false);

But at this point a different error comes out:

> The constructor SteamId(Object, boolean) is not visible

So, I'm assuming this function is internal to the API, and should not be called from the outside.

If anyone is familiar with this, or has a clue on why I'm getting this error (I'm fairly new to Java development), an answer would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

> The constructor SteamId(String) is undefined

This is if I use SteamId.create(ConvertedID); (ConvertedID is a String containing the Steam64 ID).

At this point I believe this API is not that well written, at least for java. Any other idea?

Comment: From the source on github it looks like the wiki is lying and the call should be `SteamId.create("demomenz")`

Comment: Do you still experience this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the constructor is private. Use this instead:

```
SteamId id = SteamId.create("demomenz");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using their static method to create the StreamId:

I see the following method in their API

```
/**
 * Creates a new <code>SteamID</code> instance or gets an existing one
 * from the cache for the profile with the given ID
 *
 * @param id The 64bit SteamID of the player
 * @return The <code>SteamId</code> instance of the requested profile
 * @throws SteamCondenserException if the Steam ID data is not available,
 *         e.g. when it is private
 */
public static SteamId create(String id)
        throws SteamCondenserException {
    return SteamId.create((Object) id, true, false);
}
```

usage would be:

```
SteamId streamId = SteamId.create("myId");
```